# Editing old questions

Tags: discussion, edits, etiquette

Suppose I come across old question with glaring syntax error or [Jibberish in the title](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3581686/what-is-a-windows-service-and-how-does-its-lifecycle-differ-from-a-aaastandar) - should I edit it thus throwing it to the top of the line, or leave it be?

Motivation to edit is in case someone come across it as result of a search, but as it's old and not relevant question anymore, it doesn't feel right to put it on top of the line again.

If we had the option to edit without bumping it would be ideal, but I guess such feature is not very realistic.

So, what's your opinion?

Comment: Or, in this case, perhaps vote to delete it since it was closed as "not a real question."

Comment: @tva but it has several answers - without answers I would simply downvote it and let it get chopped off automatically. With answers I'm very reluctant to delete..

Comment: @shadow - I'd be shocked if there weren't another question that's better written and covers exactly the same ground.  Just because someone answers a question that's complete junk doesn't mean that it's worth keeping the question around.

Comment: @tva so I'd go for merging the answers into that other question. If I would write long and correct answer I would hate if it will be removed just because the OP doesn't know to search or ask questions..

Comment: @shadow 1) I don't have merge capability and 2) it wasn't closed as a duplicate.  Is it even possible to merge a question not closed as a duplicate? A diamond mod would have to weigh in on that.

Comment: @tva I said this in general, don't know who have such power.. this is what I'm doing in a forum that I moderate that's all. :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'd definitely edit for searchability.  With the front page being customized to each user's favorite tags, a bump in the queue impacts far fewer people than it used to.

Comment: Example question was closed as "not a real question" -- why even edit it, just vote to delete.

Comment: @tvanfosson: Yes, definitely right for that particular example.  In the general case though, I'd edit the title.

Comment: no arguments.

Comment: Actually I just had to roll back, the OP ruined good edit with some useless jibberish.